# How to set a single line inside textfield at the bottom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

**This the code i have used inside textfield category:**
That line only shown when users touches the textField.

```
 @implementation UITextField (textField)

            -(void)textBottomLine:(UITextField *)textField
            {
                CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
                CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
                border.borderColor = [UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"].CGColor;
                border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, 4);
                border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
                [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
                textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
         }
```

but nothing i got,please anybody help me to find out solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a custom TextField class and also set delegate in that class. Like this

**.h** FIle

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>
@propery(strong)CALayer *border;
@end
```

**.m** File

```
@implementation CustomTextField
@synthesis border;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.delegate = self;
    }
return self;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, 4);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 [border removeFromSuperlayer];
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

wherever you need the text field you can use:

```
CustomTexTField *textField = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:customFrame];
[self.view addSubView:textField];
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: I dont understand which file your are telling

Comment: To avoid adding this code in each and every screen,i like declare its inside a category field..

Comment: @Bhumika You've to remove line layer in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. Else, It will add line layer for each touch event.

Comment: @Mani you also correct i think each time its create a line while user touch the textfield..

Comment: @KishoreKumar if my answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom class as per **Bhumika's** answer for `UITextField` and also use category as below.

I've created category `UITextField+Extended`

```
@interface UITextField (Extended)
-(void)addBottomLine;
-(void)removeBottomLine;
@end
```

in **.m** file

```
@implementation UITextField (Extended)
-(void)addBottomLine
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.name = @"bottomLine";
    border.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;//[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, 4);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
-(void)removeBottomLine
{
    [[self.layer.sublayers copy] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CALayer * subLayer = obj;
        if(([[subLayer name] isEqualToString:@"bottomLine"])){
            [subLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

and In Your view controller simple import class and call this method to add/remove layer using delegate.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [txtTemp resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [txtTemp addBottomLine];
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [txtTemp removeBottomLine];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First place your UITextField in UIViewController. Then select that placed UITextField and go to is property on right hand side of Xcode, from there you will find Control in that you can see alignment option in that there are two more option->Horizontal and Vertical. In vertical you can see select one which you can see in screen shoot. By clicking on that option your text data will be displayed in UITextField bottom part.

[image: In this image you can see Control->Alignment->Vetical->third option]